# Для повтора требуется обновление страницы

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Собственно, нажал upvote и получил такое:

[image: Скриншот]

Дело в том, что стрелка вверх показывается применённой, а для возврата к реальному состоянию надо обновить страницу. Надо бы при ошибке возвращать к ненажатому состоянию.

Comment: Имхо это нереально в общем случае, т.к. неизвестно какая действительно ошибка произошла. И не возникнет ли какое-то зацикливание этой ошибки при попытке сброса голосования. Более того, это настолько редко происходит, что лишнее обновление страницы не такая большая проблема.

Comment: @alexolut, произошедшая ошибка, вероятно, на сервере. Сообщение показывается рядом с кнопками голосования, т. е. известно, что ошибка произошла именно при голосовании за сообщение. Надо просто откатить состояние на клиенте, вероятность ещё одной ошибке при этом минимальна, насколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аналогичный дефект уже [зарегистрирован на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230026/339911) более 2ух с половиной лет назад. И как следует из [комментария](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230026/dont-count-votes-on-error#comment755562_230026):

> Yeah, without knowing what the error is, the page can't know if the vote has registered or not. Both options will be wrong some of the time...

в случае ошибки нельзя быть уверенным в том, что голос не зачтён. Т.к. ошибочное состояние могло быть диагностировано и на более позднем этапе голосования. Т.о. откат отображаемой страницы к варианту до *upvote* может не отражать реальную ситуацию.